Calculating Maximum LED Current for White LED Driver TPS92360 with 5V 3A Input
I’m working on a project using the TPS92360 LED driver and need help determining if it can handle a 3S10P LED configuration. Each LED has a forward voltage of 2.95V and draws 60mA.
Input Specifications:

Input Voltage: 5V
Input Current: 3A

LED Configuration:

3 LEDs in series (3S)
10 parallel strings (10P)
Forward Voltage per LED: 2.95V
Current per LED: 60mA

Questions:

Based on the datasheet, the TPS92360 features a switch current limit of 1.2A minimum. Is this the correct value to use to calculate the maximum output current capability for LEDs in parallel configurations?
The datasheet highlights a default LED current per channel of 400mA, but it doesn’t specify if this is an absolute limit per channel. Is there a formula or method to determine the exact limit?
Considering my configuration, can this driver supply enough current to support all 30 LEDs (total current 0.6A) with proper RSET adjustments?
How do I ensure the driver doesn’t exceed its thermal limits with this design?

Any guidance on how to approach this calculation or insights from experience with this driver would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment only. Answer later if nobody else does.  LED voltage times LED current times number of lives equals total power. That's easily inside the driver capability. With driver will meet the three times lead forward voltage and then the current level then it should work well. I haven't looked at the driver data sheet to be sure but it sounds good.

Data sheet heading says 1.2 amps.

There is PSpice for TI


It's a start, you have to (2.) factor in the ratio of input voltage (5 V) to output voltage (~3*LED Vf + diode drop + Vref) - and/or η: a switch current limit of 1.2 A would seem to imply an output current limit of about .54 A to .61 A minimum @ 85° C - ignoring current ripple: the limit is on switch peak current.
Note that the limit (or the temperature) shown in figure 6-2 is lower still.
In the datasheet I see neither a definition of channel, nor a mention of 400 mA (or .4 A); it features on the Product details page - as well as a package image showing three pins.
The Rset of 10.2 Ω & Vref 204 mV(datasheet) evaluates to a current of 20 mA.
There is a formula for the inductor (and switch) current at the top of page 12 of the datasheet - I guess for η they factor in Vf, not sure about Vref (VRset).
$$I_{SW} = I_{L(DC)} = \frac{V_{out}\times I_{out}}{V_{in}\times\eta}$$
I think a current limit of 1.2 A is high enough. Just. Keep an eye on deheating.
Keep an eye on deheating. (I think embedding the device in a generous blob of thermally conductive glue helps - don't expect a factor exceeding 2. The smallest heat sinks I remember were about 4*4*4 mm³.)
Sadly, figure 6-2 doesn't qualify temperature as ambient (how would the driver know?) or junction.
Assuming junction, thermal foldback may start at 30° C ambient (enclosure?), followed by thermal shutdown (and somewhat limited device life if operated such for extended periods).

Consider using two TPS92360s, a beefier driver, or cutting back on LED power.
With more power available, consider per string series resistances dropping, say, .4 V to reduce current variation between strings.
An astute way to handle this would be splitting Rset into one 3.3 Ω (low variation) resistor per string, voltage summed to the feedback pin with resistors on the order of 1 to 10 kΩ (variation/precision of secondary importance).

(Those heat sinks may have been "16 pin DIP" finned, cut down to three fins. Hey, I still have some 40-pin wide DIP heatsinks.)

(Coming to think of it, a constant current driver for parallel LEDs/strings should operate at (n-1)/n * max current at most if there's a chance of a string failing open.)
